# Github Action : Workflow not triggered when a new tag is pushed by previous workflow

Tags: git, github, github-actions

I have 3 actions:

- develop.yml (no problem with this one)
- release.yml
- tag.yml

**release.yml**

```yaml
name: Release branch CI/CD

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - release-*

jobs:
  maven-release:
    name: Perform Maven Release
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    if: "!contains(github.event.head_commit.message, '[ci skip]')"
    steps:
      - name: Setup Java JDK
        uses: actions/setup-java@v3
        with:
          distribution: 'temurin'
          java-version: 17
          server-id: github

      - name: Checkout code
        uses: actions/checkout@v3
        with:
          token: ${{ secrets.PAT }}

      - name: Configure Git user
        run: |
          git config user.name "Er-WaN"
          git config user.email "email@gmail.com"
          git config user.password ${{ secrets.PAT }}

      - name: Maven Release
        run: mvn -Darguments=-DskipTests -ntp release:prepare release:perform -DskipTests -B
        env:
          GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.PAT }}
```

**tag.yml**

```yaml
name: GitHub Release & Deploy tag

on:
  push:
    tags:
      - '**'

jobs:
  gh-release:
    name: Github Release
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Build changelog
        id: github_release
        uses: mikepenz/release-changelog-builder-action@v3
        with:
          configuration: "changelog-release.json"
        env:
          GITHUB_TOKEN: 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

      - name: Checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v3

      - name: Create GitHub release
        uses: softprops/action-gh-release@v1
        with:
          body: ${{steps.github_release.outputs.changelog}}

  deploy-dokku:
    name: Deploy to Dokku
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v3
        with:
          fetch-depth: 0

      - name: Push to dokku
        uses: dokku/github-action@master
        with:
          git_remote_url: 'ssh://dokku@dokku.fr:22/appName'
          ssh_private_key: ${{ secrets.SSH_PRIVATE_KEY }}
```

The tag is well created with release.yml workflow.
It is created by my Github account using a personal access token (PAT here).

[image]

On the other hand, the second workflow (tag.xml ) is not triggered.

I have read several discussions on the same problem:

- [Push from Action does not trigger subsequent action #25702](https://github.com/orgs/community/discussions/25702)
- [Github actions workflow not triggering with tag push](https://github.com/orgs/community/discussions/27028)
- And a lot of questions here

So I used a PAT instead of GITHUB_TOKEN.
Created in my account settings :
[image]

And then I copied the token inside a new Repository secrets
:
[image]

I specify that if I create the tag on the command line from my computer the workflow is triggered.

Thanks a lot for your help.

Erwan

Comment: If you create the tag locally, does it add `[ci skip]`?

Comment: Yes, it looks like you're preventing workflows from running by including that (see https://github.blog/changelog/2021-02-08-github-actions-skip-pull-request-and-push-workflows-with-skip-ci/)

Comment: It's not really necessary to include that `if` condition, since that's what already happens anyway.

Comment: Are you absolutely certain it uses your PAT? Try revoking it or clearing the secret and see if the workflow still works.